# Chrome extension error "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I'm trying to simply call a function in background.js from popup.js. However, I get the "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received." error.

My initial 'Handshake' message works fine without error, but my 'AnotherMessage' gets the error above.

I am trying to follow the onMessage and sendMessage documentation found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) but I might be doing something wrong.

**popup.js**

```
//works perfectly fine
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg:"Handshake"}, response => {
    if(response.error){
        console.log(response);
    }
});

//Gives error message
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg:"AnotherMessage"}, response => {
    if(response.error){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

The reason I want two 'sendMessage' is because I want to execute specific functions in background.js depending on certain logic.

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request,sender,sendResponse){
if(request.msg === "Handshake"){
    //Do something
} else if (request.msg === "AnotherMessage") {
    //Do something else
   }
});
```

UPDATE: To add a bit of context, I basically have two forms in my extension. I want to send data on form submission to my database, so '*form-1*' submission executes '*function-1*', and '*form-2*' submission should execute '*function-2*' in background.js. I'm trying to achieve the different function executions via sendMessage and onMessage.

Comment: In the background script, if you call the `sendResponse` asynchronous, you have to return `true` from the callback function.

Comment: Try putting the second sendMessage inside the callback of the first one.

Comment: Please treat me like an idiot here. I'm not sure what you mean, would you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 0):

In the background script, if you call the sendResponse asynchronous, you have to return true from the callback function

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request,sender,sendResponse){
    if (request.msg === "Handshake"){
        //Do something
    } else if (request.msg === "AnotherMessage") {
        //Do something else
   }
   return true;   
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.